# Where can I get hgweb.cgi file?

Tags: mercurial

Can anyone tell me where can I get the hgweb.cgi file mentioned here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

I'm using a Mac and I have Mercurial installed and running fine. I just want to serve multiple Mercurial repositories to my local network because this hg serve -a 0.0.0.0 works for only one repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it in the Mercurial repo: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg-stable/file/tip/hgweb.cgi